# Gute, Freie Online-Ressourcen / Good Free Online Resources

Tags: discussion

This is a community question in order to gather (and thus spread) good (i.e. reliable, maybe even scientifically founded) openly accessible online resources regarding German, we can refer to in answers.

---

Diese Community-Frage dient dazu, gute (d.h. verlässliche, idealerweise wissenschaftlich fundierte), frei zugängliche Online-Ressourcen zur deutschen Sprache zu sammeln (und damit zu popularisieren), auf die wir in Antworten verweisen können.

Comment: Anders gefragt: wäre diese Sammlung auf non-meta nicht besser aufgehoben ? So wie https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9526/36160? Da wird sie m.E. auch vom "seltenen" Besucher gefunden.

Answer (score 5):

## Etymologie / Etymology

- **Pfeifer**: *Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen* https://www.dwds.de/d/woerterbuecher#wb-etymwb
- **Grimm**: *Deutsches Wörterbuch*. http://dwb.uni-trier.de/de/
- https://de.wiktionary.org

## Synchrone Varianz / Synchronous Variance

### Regionalismen, Dialekte / Regionalisms, Dialects

- *Atlas  zur  deutschen  Alltagssprache.* https://atlas-alltagssprache.de
- **Martin, Lienhart**: *Wörterbuch der Elsässischen Mundarten.* http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=ElsWB
- *Lexikon der Luxemburger Umgangssprache* http://engelmann.uni.lu:8080/portal/WBB2009/LLU/wbgui_py?lemid=UA00001
- *Wörterbuch der Luxemburgischen Mundart* http://engelmann.uni.lu:8080/portal/WBB2009/WLM/wbgui_py
- **Follmann**: *Wörterbuch der deutsch-lothringinschen Mundarten* http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=LothWB
- **Christmann, Krämer, Post**: *Pfälzisches Wörterbuch* http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=PfWB
- **Müller, Meisen, Dittmaier, Zender**: *Rheinisches Wörterbuch* http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=RhWB
- *Schweizerisches Idiotikon* https://www.idiotikon.ch/
- *Südhessisches Wörterbuch* https://www.lagis-hessen.de/de/subjects/gsform/sn/shwb/
- *Fränkisches Wörterbuch* https://lexhelfer.wbf.badw.de/

### Soziolekte

#### Jugendsprache / Youth Language

- *Lexikon der Jugendsprache* http://hehl-rhoen.de/pdf/lexikon_der_jugendsprache.pdf

## Diachrone Varianz / Diachronic Variance

### Sprachentwicklung / Language Change

- *dwdws-Verlaufskurven* Worthäufigkeitsverläufe verschiedener Korpora https://www.dwds.de/d/plot
- *Google Ngram Viewer* https://books.google.com/ngrams
- *Google Trends* https://trends.google.com/trends/

### Sprachstufen

#### Althochdeutsch / Old High German

- **Karg-Gasterstädt, Frings**: *Althochdeutsches Wörterbuch* (Old High German Dictionary) http://awb.saw-leipzig.de/cgi/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=AWB

#### Mittelhochdeutsch / Middle High German

- **Lexer**: *Mittelhochdeutsches Handwörterbuch* (Middle High German Dictionary) http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=Lexer
- *Nachträge zum Mittelhochdeutschen Handwörterbuch von Matthias Lexer*: (Middle-High-German Dictionary)  http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=NLexer
- **Bennecke, Müller, Zarnke**: *Mittelhochdeutsches Wörterbuch* http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=BMZ

#### Frühneuhochdeutsch / Early New High German

- *Frühneuhochdeutsches Wörterbuch* (Early New High German
  Dictionary) https://fwb-online.de/

#### Neuhochdeutsch / New High German

- **Adelung**: *Grammatisch-Kritisches Wörterbuch der Hochdeutschen Mundart*
  [1793-1801] (Dictionary from 1800) http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=Adelung

### Fachsprachliche Wörterbücher / Jargon Dictionaries

- *Deutsches Rechtswörterbuch* (German Legal Dictionary) https://drw-www.adw.uni-heidelberg.de/drw-cgi/zeige
- *Wörterbuch der deutschen Winzersprache* (Dictionary of German Vine Dresser Language) https://www.wdw.uni-trier.de/onlinewb/index.php